# Output URL of open firefox tabs in terminal

Tags: command-line, firefox, tabs

I would like to find out the URLs of the currently opened firefox tabs with a terminal command. Is there any possibility?

This way I would be able to write them into a text file and look at them lateron; and safe resources (I often have many open tabs). 
I know that there is an add-on for firefox, but I would be more confortable writing my own script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The currently open URLs of the opened Firefox tabs are stored in `sessionstore.js` file which is located somewhere in `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXXXXX.default` directory.

So, you can start from something like this:

```bsh
cat $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*default/sessionstore.js | sed "s/{/\n/g" | egrep -o '"url".*"scroll"' | cut -d\" -f4
```

Using `cat` we can display that file, and with the help of `sed`, `egrep` and `cut` we select only the URLs  of the opened Firefox tabs from that file.

Comment: Double quotes needed for the `egrep` pattern in `zsh`. Other than that, nice tip, thanks :)

Comment: Would you like to describe in a few words how this command works? As I get it it is like: get content of the sessionstore.js, pipe to an operation to replace \" with \n and pipe to an operation to get all lines that begin with http? Is that right? What is the use of replacing \"?

Comment: @moon.musick Or you can use `bash -c 'cat $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*default/sessionstore.js | sed "s/\"/\n/g" | egrep http[s]*:'` and you will have no problem in any *sh. :)

Comment: @aldorado it displays the contents of `sessionstore.js` file, then replaces occurences of `"` with `\n` (a newline) and then filters out only lines containing `http` or `https`. Try displaying the file and you'll know why it needs newlines :)

Comment: In the file `sessionstore.js` there are not only the addresses of the open tabs. There are many other addresses.

Comment: This answer uses the file `sessionstore.js` of Firefox. The problem is that is that this file notoriously loses tabs. What I want here is a parallel solution, asking Firefox what his tabs are. Like in AppleScript.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Then try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17253422/2353900).

Answer (score 5):

That information is stored in `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*default/sessionstore.js` and its format is json.

The following example was made to work with PHP. It walks all firefox windows, all tabs and gets the relevant information which is the last entry inside of "entries".

If we could use xpath to parse it, it would be something like: /windows/*/tabs/last()/url (my xpath knowledge is rusty).

```
cat $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*default/sessionstore.js | php -r '
$json=json_decode(fgets(STDIN), TRUE);
foreach($json["windows"] as $w)
foreach($w["tabs"] as $t)
echo end($t["entries"])["url"]."\n";'
```

Or, with perl (but first, `sudo apt-get install libjson-pp-perl`):

```
cat $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*default/sessionstore.js | perl -e '
use JSON qw( decode_json );
my $json = decode_json(<STDIN>);
foreach my $w ( @{$json->{"windows"}} ) {
    foreach my $t ( @{$w->{"tabs"}} ) {
        print $t->{"entries"}[-1]->{"url"}."\n";
    }
}'
```

Comment: This answer uses the file `sessionstore.js` of Firefox. The problem is that is that this file notoriously loses tabs. What I want here is a parallel solution, asking Firefox what his tabs are. Like in AppleScript.

Comment: What do you mean by "loses tabs"? I'm currently running Firefox with 5 tabs and I see these 5 tabs when running these scripts. This solution walks all windows and all tabs of each window.

Comment: I mean [**this**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=698363).

Comment: The question posted by aldorado: (...) find out the URLs of the currently opened firefox tabs (...). You are talking about listing tabs that were saved after shutting down firefox. Also, that bug does not seem that notorious...

Comment: The bugs with the file *sessionstore.js* — there are several of them — show themselves when one relaunches Firefox. But they occur sooner : when Firefox writes this file. I have seen such bug occur during normal use of Firefox.

Comment: i've tested both methods for the `recovery.js`-file with 9 windows and 840 tabs and they worked like a charm! -- just after **piping** the output **into a text file** i had to set the **character map** to **ISO-8859-15** for the file of the **perl-method**...!

Answer (score 1):

This requires the `jq` package, which can be installed with `sudo apt-get install jq`:

```
jq '.windows[].tabs[].entries[].url' ~/.mozilla/firefox/xkxwaf4z.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js
```

Check the path in `~/.mozilla/firefox` and replace `xkxwaf4z` with the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can extract the current URL of the front-most/active tab in Firefox:

```
cat recovery.js | php -r '$json=json_decode(fgets(STDIN), TRUE); $tindex = $json["windows"][0]["selected"]-1; $eindex = $json["windows"][0]["tabs"][$tindex]["index"]-1; echo $json["windows"][0]["tabs"][$tindex]["entries"][$eindex]["url"];'
```

Explanation: First, it finds the index of the active tab `$tindex` and then the index of the active history entry in this tab `$eindex`.

Every 15 seconds Firefox creates a backup in `*default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js`.

Comment: php5-cli needs to be installed for this to work could you add that to your answer to improve. Is there a way to grab all of the tabs urls not just the front most? like the OP asks.

Comment: I'm aware of the mismatch of the question and my answer, however Google will direct you here if you seek the information in my answer.