# Get URL of current active tab from Firefox via command line

Tags: command-line, firefox

I am running Mozilla Firefox 54.0.

Given an already opened session of Firefox and multiple open tabs, is there a way for me to extract the currently active tab (the tab I am looking at) via command line?

I could not find anything in a [List of command line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) or on the [Mozilla Developer page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options).

My question differs from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887234/how-to-get-the-url-from-a-firefox-tab-from-the-terminal), as it neither works the intended way for me nor do I want all the tabs; I want one specific tab, the tab I am looking at.

Does anybody have an idea?

Is there maybe a way to interface with a running instance of Firefox?

Thanks for Reading

Edit: The Solution:

```
import json

f= open('~/.mozilla/firefox/RANDOM.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js' )

jdata = json.loads(f.read())

f.close()

CurrentTab = jdata.get("windows")[0].get("tabs")[jdata["windows"][0]["sel‌​ected"]-1].get("entr‌​ies")[HistLen-1].get‌​("url")

 while

HistLen = len(jdata.get("windows")[0].get("tabs")[jdata["windows"][0][‌​"selected"]-1].get("‌​entries"))
```

The `HistLen` was necessary because else I was always getting some older page I had previously opened in that tab.

Thanks for Reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution has been provided [here](https://raymii.org/s/snippets/Get_the_current_or_all_Firefox_tab_urls_in_Bash.html) which is a combination of `sed` and `python2`. Here is a little bit more clear version of it:

```
sed -n "$(
python2 <<< $'import json
f = open("/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/RANDOM.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js", "r")
jdata = json.loads(f.read())
f.close()
print str(jdata["windows"][0]["selected"])')p" <(python2 <<< $'import json
f = open("/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/RANDOM.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js", "r")
jdata = json.loads(f.read())
f.close()
for win in jdata.get("windows"):
 for tab in win.get("tabs"):
  i = tab.get("index") - 1
  print tab.get("entries")[i].get("url")'
)
```

The file it's using is:

```
/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/RANDOM.profile/sessionstore.js
```

in more recent versions you should  change it with:

```
/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/RANDOM.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js
```

**Note** that this file get regenerated every 15 second so after window being instantly changed it doesn't give you the correct URL, you have to wait some second.

---

#### How does this work?

At the first part it look for the id of active tab, it's something between 1 to count of open tabs. let's say it's "3", the code corresponding to this purpose is:

```
str(jdata["windows"][0]["selected"])
```

Next it returns a list of URLs (All open tabs) and feds it to the `stdin` of `sed`:

```
for win in jdata.get("windows"):
 for tab in win.get("tabs"):
  i = tab.get("index") - 1
  print tab.get("entries")[i].get("url")
```

So we are doing something like:

```
sed -n 3p <<< "URL1
URL2
URL3"
```

which brings us to "URL3".

Comment: Hi thanks, now I was able to string a few commands together to get the current tab open. `CurrentTab = jdata.get("windows")[0].get("tabs")[jdata["windows"][0]["selected"]-1].get("entries")[HistLen-1].get("url")` , where `HistLen = len(jdata.get("windows")[0].get("tabs")[jdata["windows"][0]["selected"]-1].get("entries"))`

Answer (score 2):

I have thought about this problem as well and finally came to a solution, inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tmonjalo/33c4402b0d35f1233020bf427b5539fa). I thoroughly inspected the objects and unfortunately, I did not find any attribute assigning a tab to be the active tab.

What I instead found was the tabs has a `lastAccessed` key and from there I computed the most recent tab.

```
import json
import lz4.block
import pathlib
from time import time

# Set up path and regex for files
path = pathlib.Path.home().joinpath('.mozilla/firefox')
# files = path.glob('*default*release*/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4')
files = path.glob('5ov6afhq.default-release-1/sessionstore-backups/recovery'+
                  '.jsonlz4')

for f in files:
    # decompress if necessary
    b = f.read_bytes()
    if b[:8] == b'mozLz40\0':
        b = lz4.block.decompress(b[8:])

    # load as json
    j = json.loads(b)
    if 'windows' in j.keys():
        for w in j['windows']:

            # Variables for keeping track of most recent tab
            most_recent_tab_index = ''
            min_time = 1000

            # run through tabs
            for t in w['tabs']:
                # Firefox does not 0-index
                i = t['index'] - 1

                # Convert time to seconds
                access_time = int((int(time()*1000) - t['lastAccessed'])/600)

                if access_time < min_time:
                    most_recent_tab_index = t['entries'][i]['url']

            print("MOST RECENT TAB: ", most_recent_tab_index)
```

Comment: This works in OSX if you change path and files in order to point to home() + "Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<yourprofilekey>.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4"  (no loop needed, but doesn't hurt.)

Comment: Unfortunately, though, it's not always reliable.  It can sometimes get behind the current actual state and tell you a recent tab that's not active (at least in my experience on OSX)

Answer (score 1):

If you use an X11-based desktop, you can try your luck with  `xprop -id` with the window ID found by `xlsclients -l`. It needs some clever use of `grep` (possibly with `grep -B... -A...`) to filter out the parts you need.