# Location of the URLs of the open tabs of Chromium browser in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, scripts, chromium, url

I want to save all URLs of opened windows of google chromium in different text files with command line. In order to do that, I would need to know where google chromium stores their current google chromium URLs in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Even though I want to write the script for chromium, I have tried [this recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338294/output-url-of-open-firefox-tabs-in-terminal) for Firefox and it didn't work. I couldn't find the sessionstore.js file anywhere.

Comment: The file `~/.mozilla/firefox/*default/sessionstore.js` is available when Firefox is closed. In case it is open check the file `~/.mozilla/firefox/*default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js` :: [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/887358/566421).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `find` which are Chromium's directories within user's home directory in this way:

```bsh
find $HOME -type d -name *mium -exec echo {} \;
```

The result should be:

```bsh
/home/<user>/.config/chromium
/home/<user>/.cache/chromium
```

Within the directory `/home/<user>/.config/chromium/Default` we can find couple of files that could be useful:

```bsh
$ ls -1t $HOME/.config/chromium/Default | grep -i 'tabs\|sess'

Current Tabs
Current Session
Session Storage
Last Tabs
Last Session
```

The problem is that, unlike [Firefox's log files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887234/how-to-get-the-url-from-a-firefox-tab-from-the-terminal/887358#887358) Chromium's log files are not in readable format and it is hard to separate the tab's history from the current URLs.

---

However, within my `Current Session` I have two open tabs:

- `https://askubuntu.com/questions/970546/location-of-url-of-opened-tabs-of-google-chromium-in-ubuntu` - that I've opened by a bookmark.
- `https://www.facebook.com/` - that  I've opened by a bookmark, but then I've to login and then clicked to the FB logo.

I was able to achieve correct result by this ugly command:

```bsh
$ cat -e $HOME/.config/chromium/Default/'Current Session' | sed -e 's/\^@/\n/g' -e '/_\/chrome/d' | grep -Po '(http|https)://\K.*' | sort -u

askubuntu.com/questions/970546/location-of-url-of-opened-tabs-of-google-chromium-in-ubuntu
www.facebook.com/?ref=logo
```

But when I open another tab and browse inside for a while the output of the above command become more fuzzy:

```bsh
$ cat -e $HOME/.config/chromium/Default/'Current Session' | sed -e 's/\^@/\n/g' -e '/_\/chrome/d' | grep -Po '(http|https)://\K.*' | sort -u

askubuntu.com/questions/970546/location-of-url-of-opened-tabs-of-google-chromium-in-ubuntu
spidersport.com/forum/
spidersport.com/forum/index.php?sid=59f48a87db485e3a321aedbf7de68e6a
spidersport.com/forum/login.php
spidersport.com/forum/login.php?sid=59f48a87db485e3a321aedbf7de68e6a
www.facebook.com/
www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=111
www.facebook.com/?ref=logo
www.spidersport.com/
```

Yes, the result is correct, because URLs of my open tabs are listed within, but there are also presented URLs from the browsing history.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ perl -nwle '$h{$_}++ for /http[[:print:]]+/g; END{print for sort keys %h;}' \
~/.config/chromium/Default/Current\ Session
```

is a reworked version of @pa4080's (that I was unable to simply add as a comment.)

Comment: Can you please explain this for those of us not very familiar with Perl?  I want an unsorted list with the most recent showing at the end.  In fact, ideally only the last one since I am primarily interested in the current URI.

Comment: @Chiwda then try
$ perl -nwle '$x=$_ for /http[[:print:]]+/g; END{print $x;}' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Current\ Session ...Yes, hard to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This command attempts to find HTTPS URLs associated with a current session of Chromium:
Here I am finding unique strings containing the word https to get the history.

strings to read string in binary files, grep to find the strings with https in them and sort -u to print only their single occurence

```
strings $HOME/.config/chromium/Default/'Current Session' |grep https| sort -u
```

Comment: Welcome and thank you for your contribution. Please [edit] your answer to explain what each part does and how that answers the question. (Also see [answer])